# Start Kafka (unable to canonicalize address localhost)

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a problem for start **Kafka** in **VM Virtualbox**. I'm using [Virtual Box 6](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_6_0) with image Ubuntu 20.04. In Ubuntu i installed [Kafka 2.12-2.31](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads) (*downloaded file .tgz*).

**When execute command for start Zookeeper, it running with success**:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

[image]

**But, when execute command for start Kafka, it not running**:

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

**and error is show for me:**

[image]

could someone help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html#systemd-ubuntu-debian-install

Comment: Hello OneCricketeer, I'm new to kafka and when reading the documentation, I couldn't understand what I should do. Anyway thanks for trying to help. After many attempts, I solved the problem just by downloading a new version of kafka (kafka_2.13-2.6.0.tgz)

Comment: I'm saying you're using Ubuntu, so using apt is the proper way to install things

Comment: Based on the first image, the Zookeeper has been started successfully.
before executing the Kafka start command, run `jps` to check if Zookeeper is running. On the other hand I'm wondering if you use a new terminal for starting Kafka, as the way you started Zookeeper will take over the terminal and if you quit, it will stop the Zookeeper server. Finally, update your question with the results and also your java version

Comment: Hello Soheil. I solved the problem just by downloading a new version of kafka (kafka_2.13-2.6.0.tgz). Anyway thanks for trying to help

Comment: Think this is due to java version on your container...
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-3779

ZK v3.4 doesn't like JDK's north of 11 it seems